# Java Spring 3 - read cookie on application init

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I'm writing an very simple authorization system. I doesn't want to use Spring Security.
I want to write very simple auth, based on sessions, cookie and MySQL.

Now, for remember me functionality I want that every time that an page loads, an method will check cookies.

I create init-bean, it works. But when I try read cookie, it fails.

For cookies I need HttpServletRequest. So this is what I do in init-bean:

```
    @Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Init-Bean started");

    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

    // Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
    //
    // for (Cookie c : cookies) {
    // System.out.println(c.toString());
    // }
}
```

I fails on getRequest

I get: Error creating bean with name 'auth': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Is there any way get HttpServletRequest  from init-bean? Is there any other way to this?

What I want is: Page load, read cookies, if cookie exists -> check if user exists in DB -> start session

Tnx.

P.S
I feel lost after mooving from PHP to Spring (in PHP it just global array, 1 row of code). iN asp.net MVC I did it in MvcApplication. But in Java SPRING 3 I has no luck...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Cookies apply to specific HTTP requests; why do you think a cookie would be present on startup? Furthermore, you might be better off writing a filter for Spring Security instead and letting it handle all the session management.

Comment: I hate Spring's xmls and ton's of unnecessary code... It must be some very simple task. Cookies and session are very simple things.

How can I "cathc" request, such that I will not need write code in every controller's method?

In ASP.NET I did it in Application class, I can't find something similar in Spring...

Comment: Modern Spring configuration doesn't need XML for most setups, and take a look at Spring Boot for a much simplified way of setting up a runtime environment. I know how to set up all the XML for a Spring `war`, but Spring Boot makes it so easy I'm using it for all my deployments now.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel lost after mooving from PHP to Spring (in PHP it just global array, 1 row of code)

This sentence makes this question make a whole lot more sense.  In Java, the servlet classes are instantiated at server startup, not at request time so when `afterPropertiesSet()` is called, no request has come in yet (in fact, there's *no way* a request could have come in because the server hasn't started accepting connections yet).  I suggest you check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106467#3106467).  The accepted answer does a great job of explaining the lifecycle of beans, etc.  Fundamentally, you will need to rethink the way you handle requests in a Java/Spring environment coming from a PHP environment.